# Node JS сервер сделать видимым из интернета

Tags: node.js

Как сделать Node JS сервер видимым из интернета?

Comment: постоянно или временно?

Comment: Скопировать его на хостинг.

Comment: Точно так же, как и *любой другой сервер*.

Answer (score 0):

Можно зарегистрироваться на [Heroku](http://heroku.com) и следуя их док-ции развенуть там свой node.js проект. Доменное имя  регистрировать не нужно. Тебе дается ссылка по которой он будет доступен. Ну, а то что этот сервер будет делать - это уже дело личное.

Comment: Ну вот свет на Heroku прям сошёлся.

Comment: Чем не угодил-то?

Comment: Да не важно. Просто, зачем человеку Heroku, если совсем не понимает в вопросе. Вот уж что ему точно не понадобится, так это возможность ловкого масштабирования и другие всякие продвинутые ништяки, с которыми у Heroku всё нормально, конечно. Но лучше-то всех - у Microsoft Azure (за $80 в месяц).

Comment: Я думаю не важно кто там лучше Microsoft или Heroku или Амазон. Просто варианты есть и это хорошо.